# Defining six functions and printing an output in python

Tags: python-3.x

So the problem is to define these six functions

```
def sphereVolume(r):
def sphereSurface(r):
def cylinderVolume(r,h):
def cylinderSurface(r,h):
def coneVolume(r,h):
def coneSurface(r,h):
```

And the write a program that prompts the user for the values of r and h, call the six functions, and print the results.

I have not tested this code because I am on a computer currently that does not have scite or python, however I've created this code on a notepad.

```
from math import pi
def sphereVolume():
    volume1=((4/3)*pi*r)**3))
    return volume1


def sphereSurface():
    area1=(4*pi*r**2)
    return area1


def cylinderVolume():
    volume2=(pi*r**2*h)
    return volume2

def cylinderSurface():
    area2=(2*pi*r**2+2*pi*r*h)
    return area2

def coneVolume():
    volume3=((1/3)*pi*r**2*h)
    return volume3

def coneSurface():
    area3=(pi*r+pi*r**2)
    return area3

main():




def main():
    r=int (input("Enter the radius:"))
    h=int (input("Enter the heights:"))
    print ("Sphere volume:",sphereVolume(r),volume1)
    print ("Sphere Surface:",sphereSurface(r),area1)
    print ("Cylinder Volume:" , cylinderVolume(r,h),volume2)
    print ("Cylinder Surface:",cylinderSurface(r,h),area2)
    print ("Cone Volume:",coneVolume(r,h),volume3)
    print ("Cone Surface:",coneSurface(r,h),area3)
```

Am I using the functions properly? Or is there a lot that I need to change?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @thefourtheye: the CR crew improves working code.  If code doesn't work, or even if the OP isn't sure that it works, it's not really appropriate for there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many syntax errors in your code:

```
volume1=((4/3)*pi*r)**3)) (You don't need extra bracket at the end)

main():  (You called this function before you declared it, only call it after you've declared it and given it attributes)


print ("Sphere volume:",sphereVolume(r),volume1)
    print ("Sphere Surface:",sphereSurface(r),area1)
    print ("Cylinder Volume:" , cylinderVolume(r,h),volume2)
    print ("Cylinder Surface:",cylinderSurface(r,h),area2)
    print ("Cone Volume:",coneVolume(r,h),volume3)
    print ("Cone Surface:",coneSurface(r,h),area3)
```

At first glance, this may all look right, however for each function you print, you give it a set of arguments that aren't meant to be there (e.g `sphereVolume` has the argument `r`). They shouldn't be there because you programmed them NOT to take in arguments, so you should change your functions  to take in the arguments, otherwise you get the error:

```
    print ("Sphere volume:",sphereVolume(r),volume1)
TypeError: sphereVolume() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

So your functions should look like this:

```
from math import pi
def sphereVolume(r):
    volume1=((4/3)*pi*r)**3
    return volume1


def sphereSurface(r):
    area1=(4*pi*r**2)
    return area1


def cylinderVolume(r,h):
    volume2=(pi*r**2*h)
    return volume2



def cylinderSurface(r,h):
    area2=(2*pi*r**2+2*pi*r*h)
    return area2

def coneVolume(r,h):
    volume3=((1/3)*pi*r**2*h)
    return volume3

def coneSurface(r,h):
    area3=(pi*r+pi*r**2)
    return area3
```

You need to give them a set of arguments to work with, otherwise it's incorrect to put the variable r and h inside the functions, because- in simple terms- they haven't been given permission to be there.

Finally, you need to remove the extra variables you got from your functions that you printed out in `main()`. As they are local variables  you can't access them unless they are returned. I'm guessing what you tried to do is that you wanted for instance in this line

```
print ("Sphere volume:",sphereVolume(r),volume1)
```

to print the value of `volume1`.  You've already done that! When you said return `volume1` at the end of the function, that meant if ever you print this function elsewhere, the only argument that will be accessed from the function is the one you returned, which in this case is `volume1`. Do the same likewise for all the other local variables you tried printing out by deleting them.

I've tested this code, but just so you don't have to look at everything I wrote if you don't want to, the fully working code is this:

```
from math import pi
def sphereVolume(r):
    volume1=((4/3)*pi*r)**3
    return volume1


def sphereSurface(r):
    area1=(4*pi*r**2)
    return area1


def cylinderVolume(r,h):
    volume2=(pi*r**2*h)
    return volume2

def cylinderSurface(r,h):
    area2=(2*pi*r**2+2*pi*r*h)
    return area2

def coneVolume(r,h):
    volume3=((1/3)*pi*r**2*h)
    return volume3

def coneSurface(r,h):
    area3=(pi*r+pi*r**2)
    return area3






def main():
    r=int (input("Enter the radius:"))
    h=int (input("Enter the heights:"))
    print ("Sphere volume:",sphereVolume(r))
    print ("Sphere Surface:",sphereSurface(r))
    print ("Cylinder Volume:" , cylinderVolume(r,h))
    print ("Cylinder Surface:",cylinderSurface(r,h))
    print ("Cone Volume:",coneVolume(r,h))
    print ("Cone Surface:",coneSurface(r,h))

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add arguments to your functions for `r` and `h`.

You have an extra paren for:

```
volume1=((4/3)*pi*r)**3))
```

You need to fix:

```
main():
```

Comment: I should say How would i add the arguments in each function?

Comment: An example would be replace def sphereVolume(): with def sphereVolume(r):